# Convert ipynb notebook to HTML in Google Colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have a Google Colaboratory Notebook for Data Analysis that I want to output as a HTML file as currently not everything loads within the Colab environment such as large Folium Heatmaps. Is it possible to export the notebook as a html file as opposed to the ipynb and py options?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Google Colab doesn't currently have such a feature as a built-in.

Your best route is to first download it through `File > Download .ipynb` and then use the standard tool for Jupyter Notebook conversion, `nbconvert`:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html notebook.ipynb
```

If you use an Anaconda Python distribution, `nbconvert` is most likely already installed. If not, refer to what is described in their [install instructions](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) to be able to convert:

```
pip install nbconvert
# OR
conda install nbconvert
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Great first answer. Minor nitpick: Conda is not a distribution of Python, Anaconda is. Conda is the package/dependency/environment manager.

Comment: Thank you Alexander! You're right, Conda is only a package/env manager, a CLI for that matter. I've accordingly edited my answer.

Comment: Nice! Found that you can do the same in Colab itself, so added that [version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64487858/8565438) too.

Answer (score 64):

## Method using Google Colab only

1. **Download your .ipynb file**

You can actually do it using only Google Colab. `File` -> `Download .ipynb`

---

2. **Reupload it so Colab can see it**

Click on the `Files` icon on the far left:

[image]

Then `Upload to session storage`:

[image]

Select & upload your `.ipynb` file you just downloaded.

---

3. **Get your file's path**

then obtain its path (you might need to hit the `Refresh` button before your file shows up):

[image]

---

4. **Conversion using %%shell**

Then, just as in [Julio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8272600/julio-cezar-silva)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55327270/8565438), execute in a Colab cell:

```
%%shell
jupyter nbconvert --to html /PATH/TO/YOUR/NOTEBOOKFILE.ipynb
```

The `%%shell` lets the interpreter know that the following script is interpreted as shell. Don't write anything before `%%shell`, use a distinct cell for this.

The form of `/PATH/TO/YOUR/NOTEBOOKFILE.ipynb` will be something like `/content/lightaberration3.ipynb`.

---

5. **Your file is ready**

Might need to click `Refresh` again, but your `notebook.html` will appear in the files, so you can download it:

[image]

---

The great thing about this is that nothing python-related has to be installed on your computer, not [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/), not [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/), only a browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is only available with an upgraded account with costs.

Comment: No, none of the steps above require upgrading. Which step is causing you trouble?

Comment: I use similar methods in EU, UK, Norway, they work in all three of these places.

Comment: This method works fine and I feel like should be the accepted answer as well! Thanks @zabop

Comment: I was getting some errors related to 'widgets' during conversion ..
`File "/...lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbconvert/filters/widgetsdatatypefilter.py", line 57, in __call__
    metadata["widgets"][WIDGET_STATE_MIMETYPE]["state"]
KeyError: 'state'
`

I had to remove the 'widgets' to make it work


`jq -M 'del(.metadata.widgets)' my_file.ipynb > my_file.fixed.ipynb`

Answer (score 0):

to continue with "Method using only Google Colab"
" %%shell jupyter nbconvert --to html /PATH/TO/YOUR/NOTEBOOKFILE.ipynb" - as given

the following worked for me - type the following in Google Colab
!pip install nbconvert

%shell jupyter nbconvert --to html /content/testfile.ipynb
(instead of using %%shell in Google Colab, use %shell - this way, it worked for me)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30967015)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download your notebook and upload it back to the colab
2. Replace `PATH_TO_THE_NOTEBOOK_IN_COLAB` in the below command to the location of the reuploaded notebook.
3. Use this command to download the notebook as html => `!jupyter nbconvert --to html PATH_TO_THE_NOTEBOOK_IN_COLAB.ipynb`.

Answer (score 0):

I did all the steps mentioned above to get the file path but then ran this code (each line in it's own cell).

!pip install nbconvert

!jupyter nbconvert -- to html /ADD YOUR FILE PATH HERE.ipynb

from google.colab import files
files.download('ADD YOUR FILE PATH HERE.html')

Answer (score -1):

I tried the approach above but couldn't get it to work - for small jobs I log onto https://jupyter.org/try , upload the downloaded ipynb file from Google Colab and then I opened the file, from here you will have the functionality in jupyter.org to download as html or whatever other format you require. It took the pain out of trying to get it to work.

Comment: Could you be more specific about which part didn't work?