# How to write cell content to PDF in Google Colab?

Tags: python, pdf, ipython, google-colaboratory

**I would like to have a cell's content written out to a pdf file in Google Colab.**

I know how to use `%%writefile` magic command to write contents to a txt file:

```
%%writefile file.txt
contents of my txt file
```

I know [how to convert the whole notebook to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64487858/8565438).

I would like to have some solution similar to:

```
%%writemypdf file.pdf
lines in my pdf
```

**Is this possible?**