# nbconvert to pdf not working in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, nbconvert

I am able to use nbconvert to HTML with the following command copied [from this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53460051/convert-ipynb-notebook-to-html-in-google-colab):

```
%%shell
jupyter nbconvert --to html /PATH/TO/YOUR/NOTEBOOKFILE.ipynb
```

but when I switch to pdf, I get the following error message:

```
CalledProcessError: Command 'jupyter nbconvert --to pdf myworkbook.ipynb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

From some cursory research it looks like nbconvert has always been a bit janky with google colab, but does anyone know what exactly is happening here, and a possible workaround? I would prefer to do the conversion right within colab rather than download the file, print to pdf and then get the output.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that nbconvert convert to pdf has a few other dependencies which are not installed in google colab. These include LateX and XeteX. From the docs page:

https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-pandoc