# How to copy colab terminal output in a text file?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I want to store colab terminal output (commands run over last 1 hour along with their output) in a text(`.txt`) file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use Capture cap in the cell whose outcome you want to store

```
%%capture cap
print("Lov Python")#Some code
```

Then run these lines

```
f = open("filename.txt", "w") 
print(cap, file=f)
f.close()
```

Then whole console saved in cap will be saves as .txt

Answer (score 0):

You can save terminal output as an HTML file. To do so you first need to download .ipynb in Google Colab through `File > Download` then use Jupyter Notebook tool `nbconvert` to convert it to .html file:

```
jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to html
```

Read this for more info: [Convert ipynb notebook to HTML in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53460051/convert-ipynb-notebook-to-html-in-google-colab)